# Batch allocation of stock on SOOrder

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to write a process screen to allocate stock on the sales order in FIFO. The Process screen list all the sales order for a period for allocation.

I have gone through the code LSSOLine and not able to figure out the piece of code where allocation is done. anybody knows how to do it?

**Update**

I have tried the following code and it is working. Is there any better way to do it?

```
private static void DoStockAllocation(SOLine row, SOOrderEntry grp)
        {
            try
            {
                grp.Document.Current = PXSelect<
                    SOOrder, 
                    Where<SOOrder.orderType, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderType>>, 
                        And<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>
                    .Select(grp, row.OrderType, row.OrderNbr);
                if (grp.Document.Current != null && grp.Document.Current.Status == SOOrderStatus.Open)
                {
                    grp.Transactions.Current = row;
                   PXSelectBase<INLocationStatus> cmd = new PXSelectReadonly2<INLocationStatus,
                InnerJoin<INLocation, On<INLocation.locationID, Equal<INLocationStatus.locationID>>,
                LeftJoin<INSiteStatus, On<INSiteStatus.inventoryID, Equal<INLocationStatus.inventoryID>,
                    And<INSiteStatus.subItemID, Equal<INLocationStatus.subItemID>,
                    And<INSiteStatus.siteID, Equal<INLocationStatus.siteID>>>>>>,
                    Where<INLocationStatus.inventoryID, Equal<Required<INLocationStatus.inventoryID>>,
                        And<INLocationStatus.subItemID, Equal<Required<INLocationStatus.subItemID>>,
                        And<INLocationStatus.siteID, Equal<Required<INLocationStatus.siteID>>,
                        And<INLocation.salesValid, Equal<boolTrue>,
                        And<INLocation.inclQtyAvail, Equal<boolTrue>,
                        And<INLocationStatus.qtyOnHand, Greater<decimal0>>>>>>>>(grp);

                    foreach (PXResult<INLocationStatus, INLocation, INSiteStatus> ln in cmd.Select(row.InventoryID,row.SubItemID,row.SiteID))
                    {
                        INLocationStatus locationStatus = ln;
                        INSiteStatus siteStatus = ln;
                        SiteStatus accumsiteavail = new SiteStatus();
                        PXCache<INSiteStatus>.RestoreCopy(accumsiteavail, siteStatus);
                        accumsiteavail = (SiteStatus)grp.Caches[typeof(SiteStatus)].Insert(accumsiteavail);

                        decimal? AvailableQty = 0m;


                        decimal? SiteAvailableQty = locationStatus.QtyHardAvail;//siteStatus.QtyHardAvail + accumsiteavail.QtyHardAvail;


                        AvailableQty = SiteAvailableQty;
                        if (AvailableQty <= 0m)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (row.LocationID == null)
                        {
                            row.LocationID = locationStatus.LocationID;
                            grp.Transactions.Update(row);
                        }
                        SOLineSplit split = new SOLineSplit();
                        if ( grp.splits.Select().Count > 0)
                        {
                            split = grp.splits.Select(row.OrderType, row.OrderNbr, row.LineNbr); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            split =  new SOLineSplit();
                            split = grp.splits.Insert(split);
                            split.InventoryID = row.InventoryID;
                            split.SiteID = row.SiteID;
                            split.OrderType = row.OrderType;
                            split.OrderNbr = row.OrderNbr;
                            split.LineNbr = row.LineNbr;
                            split.UOM = row.UOM;
                            split = PXCache<SOLineSplit>.CreateCopy(grp.splits.Update(split));
                        }
                        //split.LocationID = locationStatus.LocationID;
                        split.Qty = (AvailableQty < row.OrderQty) ? AvailableQty : row.OrderQty;
                        split.IsAllocated = true;
                        grp.splits.Update(split);
                        break;

                    }
                    grp.Save.Press();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the combination of LSSOLine and SOLineSplitPlanID on  SOLineSplit.PlanID in your process page. Alternatively you might be able to use an instance of SOOrderEntry to do the updates/mark of allocation.

The following have been copied from the SOOrderEntry graph and are the 2 componenetis from what i can tell that drive the allocation logic. From there you just need to mark the split lines that should be allocated and should be good. Or at least a start. The problem you might have is anything that is looking for current SOOrder. You might have to set the current before marking solines splits as allocated. (assuming i under stand your question correctly)

Manage the allocation records...

```
public LSSOLine lsselect;
```

Append the use of SOLineSplitPlanID which drives the INItemPlan records...

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[SOLineSplitPlanID(typeof(SOOrder.noteID), typeof(SOOrder.hold), typeof(SOOrder.orderDate))]
protected virtual void SOLineSplit_PlanID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

Comment: I am using SOOrderEntry and setting the Transactions.Current with the SOLine to be allocated

Comment: If that is the case then not sure what the question is? Are you just trying to check mark the allocation check box on the SOLineSplit record?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to load the sales order into the SOOrderEntry graph and then mark the split lines you want as allocated as allocated. If not enough on hand the code should prevent the set of Allocated just like the user receives in the UI.